# (Tkinter) How to color objects using this pattern?

Tags: python, animation, tkinter, rgb, physics

I tried coloring objects, following an equal pattern to electrical field (responding to the placement of a specific type of objects called "charge"). Color is a way of representing the intensity of the electric field: whenever the electric field is positive there will be a shade of red, if it is negative, blue, and if the field is 0 it will be black (objects are representations of points in space, they are a way of "discretizing" space, I placed them inside a matrix).

The goal of this is to make a representation of the electric field similar to the representation of the potential of this [PhET simulation.](https://phet.colorado.edu/sims/html/charges-and-fields/latest/charges-and-fields_es.html)

Based on the principle of super position, my attempt was to define a function that first does a calculation of the distance of the charge towards each object, then I tried to color each object by adding values ​​in the red channel (I am assuming that the placed charge is positive), according to its position, as long as its values ​​in this channel are within a limit or the object is completely black; in case it has values ​​in the blue channel, it will subtract them. And vice versa for blue.

```
def ncolor(r,g,b):
    nr = int(r)
    ng = int(g)
    nb = int(b)
    color = "#%4.4x%4.4x%4.4x" % (nr,ng,nb)
    return color

def interaction(charge, pol): 
    for o in range(columnobjects):
        for p in range(rowobjects):
            (r, g, b) = window.winfo_rgb(canvas.itemcget(objectop, "fill"))
            dis = math.sqrt((charge.x - objectoj.x)**2 + (charge.y - objectoj.y)**2)
            if pol == 0: 
                if dis <= 100: 
                    if float(r)==0 and float(b)==0 or 0 < float(r) < 10536: 
                        (r,g,b) = np.array((r,g,b))+np.array((5268*2, 0, 0))
                        color = ncolor(r,g,b)
                        canvas.itemconfig(objectop, fill=color)
                    elif float(r)==0 and float(b)!=0:
                        (r,g,b) = np.array((r,g,b))-np.array((0, 0, 5268*2))
                        color = ncolor(r,g,b)
                        canvas.itemconfig(objectop, fill=color)
                elif 100 < dis <= 200: 
                    if float(r)==0 and float(b)==0 or 0 < float(r) < 52680: 
                        (r,g,b) = np.array((r,g,b))+np.array((5268, 0, 0))
                        color = ncolor(r,g,b)
                        canvas.itemconfig(objectop, fill=color)
                    elif float(r)==0 and float(b)!=0:
                        (r,g,b) = np.array((r,g,b))-np.array((0, 0, 5268))
                        color = ncolor(r,g,b)
                        canvas.itemconfig(objectop, fill=color) 
            else: pass    
            if pol == 1: 
                if dis <= 100: 
                    if float(r)==0 and float(b)==0 or 0 < float(r) < 10536: 
                        (r,g,b) = np.array((r,g,b))+np.array((0, 0, 5268*2))
                        color = ncolor(r,g,b)
                        canvas.itemconfig(objectop, fill=color)
                    elif float(r)==0 and float(b)!=0:
                        (r,g,b) = np.array((r,g,b))-np.array((5268*2, 0, 0))
                        color = ncolor(r,g,b)
                        canvas.itemconfig(objectop, fill=color)
                elif 100 < dis <= 200: 
                    if float(r)==0 and float(b)==0 or 0 < float(r) < 52680: 
                        (r,g,b) = np.array((r,g,b))+np.array((0, 0, 5268))
                        color = ncolor(r,g,b)
                        canvas.itemconfig(objectop, fill=color)
                    elif float(r)==0 and float(b)!=0:
                        (r,g,b) = np.array((r,g,b))-np.array((5268, 0, 0))
                        color = ncolor(r,g,b)
                        canvas.itemconfig(objectop, fill=color) 
            else: pass
```

When I ran it I realized that this is nothing like the behavior of an electric field produced by n charges. It occurs to me that, perhaps, I could directly apply the definition of electric field to the distance, and use the result in the rgb channels, but I don't know how to deal with negative values ​​(I am new to working with rgb).